# Python count occurrences of different item types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file containing infection data for hospital patients from 2007-present, imported into a pandas dataframe. Each entry contains standard patient details like age, bmi etc. If the patient has an infection, they will also have data on: the date the infection was found, what microbe it is (number coded), and whether it is gram positive/negative/fungi/unknown. A patient can have at most 3 different microbes. Out of 18k entries, about 400 have infections. You can see a (simplified) snapshot of the dataset below. (Standard patient details have been removed as they're not relevant to my question)

```
  PatientID DateOp  DateOnset   1_CODE  1_TYPE  2_CODE  2_TYPE  3_CODE  3_TYPE
1   21/08/2011  28/08/2011  276 Gram Neg                
2   31/08/2011  08/10/2011  922 Fungi               
3   01/12/2011  15/12/2011  113 Gram Neg    780 Gram Pos        
4   01/12/2011  08/12/2011  113 Gram Neg                    
5   20/03/2012  24/03/2012  424 Gram Neg    276 Gram Neg        
6   16/12/2011  21/12/2011  221 Gram Neg                
7   23/04/2012  26/04/2012  922 Gram Pos    311 Gram Neg    780 Gram Pos
8   19/05/2012  29/05/2012  772 Gram Pos                
9   08/02/2012  13/02/2012      Unknown
```

I want to see how many of each microbe type (pos/neg/fungi/other) has occurred in each month since 2007 (using `DateOnset` as the date), and plot this in a suitable chart - for example a stacked bar-chart coloured by microbe type.

I thought I could do this by creating new columns in `ssidf`: `gram_pos`, `gram_neg`, `fungi`, `other`. Then, iterate through `1_TYPE`, `2_TYPE`, `3_TYPE`, and if there is an infection in a row, add `1` to the necessary column(s). This is how I thought I could achieve this:

```
for row in ssidf.1_TYPE:
   if ssidf.1_TYPE[row].str.contains('Gram Pos') is True:
      ssidf.gram_pos[row] == 1
   elif ssidf.1_TYPE[row].str.contains('Gram Neg') is True:
      ssidf.gram_neg[row] == 1
   elif ssidf.1_TYPE[row].str.contains('Fungi') is True:
      ssidf.fungi[row] == 1
   else:
      ssidf.unknown[row] == 1
```

This is my expected result:

```
   DateOnset    gram_pos    gram_neg    fungi   unknown
28/08/2011  0   1   0   0
08/10/2011  0   0   1   0
15/12/2011  1   1   0   0
08/12/2011  0   1   0   0
24/03/2012  0   2   0   0
21/12/2011  1   0   0   0
26/04/2012  2   1   0   0
29/05/2012  1   0   0   0
13/02/2012  0   0   0   1
```

Then, I would sum the totals of `gram_pos`, `gram_neg`, `fungi`, `other` per month, and represent them in a stacked bar chart.

However, I'm falling at the first hurdle - the for loop. I keep getting: `KeyError: 'Gram Neg'`. I haven't even tried to get it to iterate across `2_TYPE` and `3_TYPE` yet, because the first column isn't working. Can anyone see what the problem is and suggest how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [iterating in pandas is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/13138364). It's more idiomatic to reshape and cross-tabulate.

1. [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) the `DateOnset`/`TYPE` columns with `DateOnset` as the id:

   ```
   melted = ssidf[['DateOnset', '1_TYPE', '2_TYPE', '3_TYPE']].melt('DateOnset')

   #      DateOnset variable     value
   # 0   28/08/2011   1_TYPE  Gram Neg
   # 1   08/10/2011   1_TYPE     Fungi
   # 2   15/12/2011   1_TYPE  Gram Neg
   # ..         ...      ...       ...
   # 24  26/04/2012   3_TYPE  Gram Pos
   # 25  29/05/2012   3_TYPE       NaN
   # 26  13/02/2012   3_TYPE       NaN
   ```
2. [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) the melted `DateOnset` vs melted `value`:

   ```
   xtab = pd.crosstab(melted['DateOnset'], melted['value'])

   # value       Fungi  Gram Neg  Gram Pos  Unknown
   # DateOnset                                     
   # 08/10/2011      1         0         0        0
   # 08/12/2011      0         1         0        0
   # 13/02/2012      0         0         0        1
   # 15/12/2011      0         1         1        0
   # 21/12/2011      0         1         0        0
   # 24/03/2012      0         2         0        0
   # 26/04/2012      0         1         2        0
   # 28/08/2011      0         1         0        0
   # 29/05/2012      0         0         1        0
   ```
3. Aggregate the monthly counts using [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) (optionally renaming the index with [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)):

   ```
   xtab.index = pd.to_datetime(xtab.index)
   (xtab.groupby([xtab.index.year, xtab.index.month]).sum()
        .rename_axis(['YearOnset', 'MonthOnset']))

   # value                 Fungi  Gram Neg  Gram Pos  Unknown
   # YearOnset MonthOnset                                    
   # 2011      8               1         2         0        0
   #           12              0         2         1        0
   # 2012      2               0         0         0        1
   #           3               0         2         0        0
   #           4               0         1         2        0
   #           5               0         0         1        0
   ```

Comment: I believe the OP mentions they wish to aggregate by month - not the exact date...

Comment: My understanding is that OP is just asking how to generate this table, and they will do the aggregation themselves afterwards.

Comment: @JonClements I went ahead and added the monthly table just in case.

Comment: @tdy Thank you very much for this, steps 1&2 worked perfectly! For step 3 I decided to just group by year, so was able to use year_group = xtab.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="Y")) to get the desired result.